# VirtualBox consuming 100% CPU even when guest is idle

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I've tried all the solutions available on different forums. This is the configuration of my system.

[image]
[image]

I'm using Oracle VM VirtualBox ver. 4.3.14 r95030

[image]

This is the confuguration of my guest:

[image]

The task manager of my host shows 100% CPU activity even when the guest is idle.

[image]

I've also made a DOS machine which is suggested to do nothing and that reduces the CPU activity to about 56% but not as same as it should be when my host and guests are idle.

[image]

Another solution available to me was to setting the affinity of VirtualBox to a single processor but I'm not able to do that, it denied the access. I'm logged in administrator and also have checked "Show processes from all users"

[image]

Please help me. Many many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: or maybe http://superuser.com

Comment: similar question on superuser from same user: http://superuser.com/questions/809396/virtualbox-consuming-100-cpu-even-when-the-guest-is-idle